# Extract coefficients from trigonometric polynomial

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

Suppose I have:

```
f[r_, ϕ_] = C1 Cos[ϕ]r + C3 Sin[3 ϕ] r + C4 Sin[4 ϕ] r^4;
```

How do I extract the coefficient of a chosen trigonometric term, let's say `Cos[ϕ]`?

Comment: `Coefficient[f[r, \[Phi]], Cos[\[Phi]]]`

Comment: @Hubble07 answer?

Comment: If `f` is meant to be an expression obtained from a computation, then the form of the expression might determine the answer.  For example, `Coefficient[TrigExpand@f[r, ϕ], Cos[ϕ]]`.  If this is an issue, `FourierCoefficient` might be appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 Coefficient[f[r, ϕ], Cos[ϕ]]
```